# multiarch and Architecture: all packages

Tags: multiarch

I have a problem with multiarch: I installed Ubuntu 13.04 amd64 and it works well. Unfortunately I have a Philips LaserMFD 6020 Printer/Scanner and for the scanner part it has only a proprietary i386 linux driver. To use it, I tried a multiarch installation:

- I installed sane:i386 (apt-get install sane:i386) for xscanimage, and it works well
- I tried to install the more comfortable simple-scan:i386 and xsane:i386, but I can't: both has an unmet dependencies (xsane-common:i386 and gnome-icon-theme:i386).

It is true, there is no such a package as xsane-common:i386 because xsane-common is for all architecture. Is there any way to install an i386 package with dependencies to Architecture: all packages without broke the package management?

Answer (score 1):

The architecture-independent package needs to declare that it can safely satisfy dependencies on any architecture, with `Multi-Arch: foreign` or `Multi-Arch: allowed`. So, no, there's not much you can do.