# Multiarch issue with packages marked as supporting "all" architectures

Tags: apt, dpkg, multiarch

I have added foreign architecture to my `amd64` system, e.g. `arm64`.
Let's suppose I want to install `libproj9:arm64`. I get the following error:

`libproj9:arm64 : Depends: proj-data:arm64 but it is not installable`

Now looking at `proj-data` package ([here](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/libs/proj-data)), you can see that architecture support is `all`. So in theory installing `proj-data` as `apt-get install proj-data` should provide support for all architectures, i.e. is architecture independent.

However... the package manager is looking for `proj-data:arm64` and naturally cannot find it and is failing.

- Is there a known way to overcome this? In case it matters, I am under Xenial (Ubuntu 16.04).
- Or should I manually edit the `.deb` file [as hinted here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/286463/multiarch-and-architecture-all-packages) and try to trick dpkg?

Comment: Are you sure it's an architecture conflict and not a version conflict?

Comment: Yeap. So I tried my second suggestion:

  1. I downloaded `proj-data`: `apt-get download proj-data`
  2. I used `fpm` to change the `control` file of the `.deb`: `fpm -e -s deb -t deb ../proj-data_4.9.2-2_all.deb`
  3. In the control file I change this line: `Architecture: all` to `Architecture: arm64`
  4. I installed the new `.deb`: `dpkg -i <deb_file>`

And now `libproj9:arm64` is not complaining any more.

Answer (score 1):

So as I suspected there is a `hacky` solution for now, which I don't like but at least it allows me to continue working. In case someone is interested in a temp solution:

- I downloaded `proj-data`: `apt-get download proj-data`
- I used fpm to change the control file of the .deb: `fpm -e -s deb -t deb ../proj-data_4.9.2-2_all.deb`
- In the control file I change this line: `Architecture: all` to `Architecture: arm64`.

  > **Update:** Based on [documentation](https://wiki.debian.org/Multiarch/CrossDependencies#all_vs_any_-dev_packages) using actually `Architecture: any` should be the way (but I haven't tested).
- I installed the new `.deb`: `dpkg -i <deb_file>`

And now `libproj9:arm64` is not complaining finding `proj-data:arm64` any more.

Comment: According to [wiki.debian.org](https://wiki.debian.org/Multiarch/CrossDependencies#all_vs_any_-dev_packages), it should be changed from `Achitecture: all` to `Architecture: any`

Comment: thanks Cesar, based on the link you provided I agree! Haven't tested it but I will add this